# How to resolve Electron ffmpeg error opening input file?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, electron

I have an Electron app with `ffmpeg.exe` inside the project's `bin` folder. When i try to use ffmpeg to make a new video I get an error reading the input file.

```
FFmpeg error: [in#0 @ 000002667f2ab9c0] Error opening input: No such file or directory

Error opening input file C:/Users/xxxx/Videos/Powder/2023.08.19%2017.30.37_Apex_Legends/Powder_2023.08.19%2021.00.48.mp4
```

```js
const ffmpeg = spawn(ffmpegPath, [
  '-i', videoFile,
  '-filter_complex', filterComplex,
  '-map', '[out]',
  '-c:v', 'libx264',
  '-crf', '18',
  '-preset', 'veryfast',
  '-y',
  path.join(outputDir, outputName)
]);

ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`FFmpeg output: ${data}`);
});

ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`FFmpeg error: ${data}`);
});

ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`FFmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
  event.reply('ffmpeg-export-done'); // Notify the renderer process
});
```

How can i resolve this path issue?

Comment: Do the first 2 lines of the output you posted come together? It's part of the `${data}` in stderr? Check if it works with input and output set to files in the drive root, like `c:/input.mp4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to decode the file path as it was in URI format.

```js
const decodeURI = (uri) => {
  return uri.replace(/%[0-9A-F]{2}/g, match => String.fromCharCode('0x' + match.slice(1)));
};
```